# Bookmarking an on-screen position in macOS?

Tags: macos, screen

When looking at something in macOS, how can I put some kind of horizontal line so that I don't forget my position on the screen?

Let's say I'm reading a list shown on the screen,
and I've mentally processing the bottom quarter of the list, so I want to **put a marker there** so that when I come back from lunch I know where I need to resume from.

My ad hoc solution so far has been to position a Finder window at the point where my region starts. But I end up using Finder for other tasks and can easily loose my "bookmark".

Comment: I think you've just proposed some simple elegant widget, that clips riders on content positions of other programs (so the rider scrolls along with content) and then with hotkeys or a floating menu you can find all of your riders back.

Answer (score 8):

A possible alternative to using a Finder window as a bookmark is using the built-in Stickies app (if you are not using the apps as a fullscreen space).

Simply open the Stickies app and make a new note via File > New Note. While the sticky window is selected, you can make it float on top of other windows at Window > Float on Top. This will make the sticky note remain on top of the other window, regardless of app focus. You can resize the sticky to your liking and you can even collapse it to make it much smaller.

It's not an elegant solution and it falls apart if the sticky or the window are moved, but it is better than using Finder as a bookmark.

Here is an example of what it looks like floating on a list of numbers on an active Chrome window:

[image]

Comment: Stickies is such an unattended and underused app.

Comment: Good idea, but I'd go with one of the many screenruler apps --- the transparency helps, in my opinion. You can have various forms (angle, horizontal or vertical line). Anything with a high "z-index" (in CSS speak) would do, really, to be printed on top.

Answer (score 4):

You can use Digital Color Meter app and use it to select the location on your screen where your mouse is..  You can set it to display the coordinates of your mouse location and to display small a locked Image of where your mouse is.

You can then minimize Digital Color Meter app and when you bring it back to the foreground it will retain the original mouse coordinates and the image

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Move the window containing your list so the screen edge indicates your position.